# mongoose schema findone and update array subdocument

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my mongoose schema:

userId is a unique number generated by Okta for user profiles.
'''

```
var book_listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

userId:{type: String, required: true},
first_name: { type: String, required: true},
last_name:{ type: String, required: true},
newList: [{

         list_name: String,
         books:
    [{
        book_name: {type: String, required: true},
        book_author: {type: String, required: true},
        date_added: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        date_finished: {type: Date, default: Date.now},

    }]}],


    });

'''
```

This is the code I'm using to find and update, adding a book to the books array.

```
 '''
 book_list.findOneAndUpdate({"userId": req.userContext.userinfo.sub, newList:{"newList.list_name": list_name}}, {$push:{books:{book_name: title, book_author:author, date_added: new Date()}}}

 '''
```

The books array does not get updated and each object in newList has the list_name, and there are different lists each with their own books array, so the correct list needs to be updated when a book is added.

Sample data set:

```
  '''
            _id:625c81d7622b044fb297ce54

             userId:"00uvgyn7OikAwud6"
             first_name:"John"
             last_name:"Smith"
             newList:Array
                 0:Object
                   list_name:"read"
                   books:Array
                      0:Object
                      book_name:"The Great Gatsby"
                      book_author:"Francis Scott Fitzgerald"
                      date_added:2022-04-19T00:43:24.248+00:00
                     _id:625e05ac083663dc44f37804
                    date_finished:2022-04-19T00:43:24.252+00:00
                    _id:625e05ac083663dc44f37803
                    __v:0
  '''
```

Comment: where is "userId" coming from. I don't see that in your schema.

Comment: What does your data look like that you are sending the request with?

Comment: @DylanL. I edited my question and added the entire schema. The "userid" is random number generated by Okta for user profile. It has nothing to do with pushing book info into the books array.

Comment: can you also provide a sample dataset? one that you are sending in?

Comment: @DylanL. Hi, I added a sample dataset.

Comment: Hello, I mean data that you are submitting

Comment: do you want to add new object in that array or you want to update the same existing object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is:

```
db.collection.update({
  userId: "00uvgyn7OikAwud6",
  newList: {
    $elemMatch: {
      list_name: "read"
    }
  }
},
{
  $push: {
    "newList.$.books": {
      book_name: "a new book",
      book_author: "some author",
      date_added: new Date()
    }
  }
})
```

or in your code way

```
db.collection.update({
  userId: req.userContext.userinfo.sub,
  newList: {
    $elemMatch: {
      list_name: list_name
    }
  }
},
{
  $push: {
    "newList.$.books": {
      book_name: title,
      book_author: author,
      date_added: new Date()
    }
  }
})
```

$elemMatch allows you to match more than one component within the same array element and then you can use $push to add the specific object in the array.

You can run it here to check the same query https://mongoplayground.net/p/YnzDRfhwpEt

You can also have a look at documentation of $elemMatch in this [link](https://mongoing.com/docs/reference/operator/query/elemMatch.html).

Let me know if you face any issue.